# PeriodicRequest does not work. I tried sending a notification every 15 min and it does not work

Tags: java, android

So I used PeriodicRequest to send a notification to me every 15 minutes but it does not appear at all. Once I kill the app, the option to force shut is disabled. Doesn't this mean that there is no background precesses running? Is that the reason my notification does not appear?

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder((BackgroundWork.class),
            15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

The code below is from BackgroundWork class.

```
    public Result doWork() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder alertNotify = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(context1,"101")
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Test notif")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.virus)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .setAutoCancel(true); //removes notification when user clicks

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context1);
    notificationManager.notify(28,alertNotify.build());
    DataParser download = new DataParser(context);
    download.execute("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
    return Result.success();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't setup the notification channel that you are trying to add the notification to. As a test can you add this code before the `NotificationCompat.Builder` setup?

```
//Kotlin
val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel("101", "Test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT))
}

//Java
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context1);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel("101", "Test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
}
```

Notification must be assigned to Channels in Android 8.0 (API level 26). Please see the NotificationChannel documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

This is most likely the reason the Notification is not showing on your device, however the Worker is definitely still working. You can see some logs of what your Workers have done in both the Debug output and Logcat windows. Some examples of my own tests can be seen below:

```
//Debug log
I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=aa30d1f6-8683-43b8-bf6d-67e7b38a6d75, tags={ com.test.stackoverflowtest.BackgroundWork } ]

//Logcat
2020-06-20 15:02:23.743 4827-4899/com.test.stackoverflowtest I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=aa30d1f6-8683-43b8-bf6d-67e7b38a6d75, tags={ com.test.stackoverflowtest.BackgroundWork } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes I had added a notification channel. Still i will check the logcat. Thank you

Comment: I checked against a API 26 emulator, with and without a Channel. Without a channel setup the Notification never appears, however with the Channel it does. Can you confirm what API you are testing against?